# Swift: How to offset index on tableView when using more than one TableViewCell class?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView that uses two classes: CustomCellOne and CustomCellTwo. CustomCellTwo is displayed at indexPath.row == 1, CustomCellOne is displayed the rest of the time.

CustomCellOne displays data from an array called tableArray. However, the cells after CustomCellTwo are missing one element from the array as the second item in the array is being replaced by CustomCellTwo within the table.

The only solution I can currently think of for this would be to add a redundant element to tableArray as indexPath 1 which would then be skipped but that does not seem elegant.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellTwo", for: indexPath) as! CustomCellTwo

        cell.label.text = ""
        return cell
    } else {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellOne, for: indexPath) as! CustomCellOne

    cell.label.text = tableArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decrement your index when it is greater than `1`.  You can do this by introducing a `row` value and then adjust it as appropriate:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellTwo", for: indexPath) as! CustomCellTwo

        cell.label.text = ""
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellOne, for: indexPath) as! CustomCellOne
        let row = indexPath.row < 1 ? 0 : indexPath.row - 1
        cell.label.text = tableArray[row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Note: You will need to return `tableArray.count + 1` as the number of rows in section `0` to account for the inserted cell at row `1`.